# How to do inner ui-view in angular js router with multiple page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following page:

```
  <div class="header"></div>
       <ui-view></ui-view>
  <div class="footer"></div>
```

and my config of my page is :

```
 .state('reports', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "src/r.php",
        controller: 'RController',
        controllerAs: 'R'
       })
       .state('data', {
             url: "/data/:dataID",
             templateUrl: "src/data.php",
             controller: 'DataController',
             controllerAs: 'vm',
        });
```

Now I would like to add another page called "test" . , but this page i want to use inner ui-view . so the page will looks like:

```
<div class="testPage">
   <div ui-view="users"></ui-view>
   <div ui-view="another"></ui-view>
</div>
```

**my question is How to add it to the routing

I tried the following but i got empty view:**

```
 .state('data', {
                url: "/data",
                templateUrl: "src/data.php",
               //controller: 'DataController', // i tried also with and without this
                //controllerAs: 'Data',// i tried also with and without this
                views: {
                     'users': {
                       templateUrl: 'src/data/users.php',
                       controller: 'UsersController',
                       controllerAs: 'vm',
                     }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the state declaration, the templateUrl should refer to the page with a view named 'users'

```
.state('data', {
                url: "/data",
                templateUrl: "src/data.php",
                views: {
                     'users': {
                       templateUrl: 'src/data/users.php', // This should be 'test' page or some other page with a view named 'users'
                       controller: 'UsersController',
                       controllerAs: 'vm',
                     }
              }
```